# When is the last time we see the Gamma Quadrant in Star Trek: Deep Space Nine?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

When is the last time we see the Gamma Quadrant in *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*? I recall it felt like it was quite far from the end of the series but I cannot recall which episode was the last and what the content of that episode was (i.e. the reason to visit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last episode featuring an *adventure* in the Gamma Quadrant is [DS9: Children of Time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Children_of_Time_(episode)) toward the end of season 5.

> Captain's log, stardate 50814.2. The Defiant is returning to Deep Space 9 after a week-long reconnaissance mission in the Gamma Quadrant.

---

We don't then see the Gamma Quadrant side of the wormhole until the show's finale episode, [DS9: What You Leave Behind](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What_You_Leave_Behind_(episode)) when Odo returns to his people at the end of season 7.